# how to clock gating EFM32LG230 for PA15 PE15 pins blinking LED

Tags: embedded

i am trying to blink LED's which are connected to PA15 PE15 on my controller, as shown in the diagram bellow.

I have tried to look in the data sheet and reference manual for their memory locations and also for the clock gating address which enables the options for controlling PA15 PE15 , from the links bellow.
As shown in the tables bellow, i found that GPIO goes from 0X40007000 -0X40006000
but i coudnt find what addersess are relevant for PA15 PE15 and what clock gating addreses are relevant for enabling PA15 PE15.

please help.

Thanks.
https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/reference-manuals/EFM32LG-RM.pdf

https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/data-sheets/efm32lg-datasheet.pdf
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Check examples available in mcu website.https://www.silabs.com/documents/public/example-code/an0009.1-efr32-efm32-getting-started.zip

Comment: could you help me with the manual issues i showed?
Thanks

Comment: I am seeing example code is more than enough to implement your requirement. Only thing you have to customize is macros LED_PORT and LED_PIN

Comment: Hello i have EFM3232LG230 which is leopard gecko , i have PE15 and PA15 so i need port E and port A with pins 15 to blink my leds.I have witten a code a shown bellow based on the example.its missing th actual blinking part.
how to accomplish it?
Thanks
#include "em_device.h"
#include "em_cmu.h"
#include "em_gpio.h"
#include "em_chip.h"
  #define LED_PORT_E    gpioPortE
  #define LED_PIN     15
  #define LED_PORT_A    gpioPortA
  #define LED_PIN     15
  void Delay(uint16_t milliseconds)
{
  
}


int main(void)
{  

  CHIP_Init();  
  

  while(1);
  
}

Comment: I suggest update the question with code in the comment.